# Cmd is not showing Java Version

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am running for `Java -version` & `javac -version` in my cmd, but it isn't showing any output.
It just goes to the next line, and doesn't show anything.
Can anyone here can help me. Any solution ,guys?
I have also added an environment variable for it.
I have attached a screenshot of it.

[image]

Comment: Do your environment is set?

Comment: What environment variable did you add? And what value does it have? Because I would assume one (or both) are not correct. Also did you add that to your `PATH`?

Comment: I just guess there is some vc-runtime-rdist library is missing in the environment.
Could you find the java.exe/javac.exe, and use some depend-x86/x64.exe to find the 
dependency?

Comment: In PowerShell (not cmd) try using `where.exe java.exe` to see which location your Path is using to find `java` command.

Comment: looks like ytou hjave a noop script n amed java on your path

Comment: Hi , Harry . yes my environment is set.

Comment: In user variable -var name-`JAVA_HOME` value-`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333`

Comment: In system variable-`JAVA_HOME `value-`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333`  and path is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: After runnung command on power shell i got this result     -                                       
`PS C:\Users\absasahu> where.exe java.exe
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
                                            C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333\bin\java.exe`

Comment: Reinstall java then

Comment: Reinstalled Java , still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to this.

Here this came after running the command `where java.exe`,
here I see that I have two java.exe. On inside Common files and another inside Java. So , Because of this only I wasn't getting the answer.

```
PS C:\Users\absasahu> where.exe java.exe 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe 
                                            
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333\bin\java.exe
```

After deleting the first java.exe file, I got my work done.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSKal.png

Answer (score 0):

Hi download java this one:

https://download.oracle.com/java/19/latest/jdk-19_windows-x64_bin.exe ( sha256)
Then go Settings , environment variable , JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\NewJava . I created newJava as folder while installing Java . and also set path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\NewJava\bin

Then type in command prompt java -version